# How do I get the current caret position?

Tags: sublimetext2

I have written a simple ST2 plugin that should just insert a timestamp at the current caret position. However, I am unable to find out how to get the current position.

I have

```
def run(self, edit):
    timestamp = "%s" % (datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
    pos = ???
    self.view.insert(edit, pos, timestamp)
```

What should `pos` be?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try with

```
pos = self.view.sel()[0].begin()
```

This gets the start point of the current selection (if nothing is selected, start and end of selection are the current cursor position).

If you want this to work with multiple selection, you have to iterate on all selections returned by `self.view.sel()`:

```
for pos in self.view.sel():
    self.view.insert(edit, pos.begin(), timestamp)
```